# Reference request : $I$-adic smoothness

Tags: formal-schemes, nonnoetherian, completion

The following result has been know for a while now:

Let $f:\mathfrak X \rightarrow \mathfrak Y$ be an adic morphism of (locally) Noetherian formal schemes and $K\subset \mathcal O_{\mathfrak Y}$ and $J=f^*(K)\mathcal O_{\mathfrak X}$ ideals of definition.

Then the morphisms $f_n$ are smooth if, and only if, it is flat and the morphism $f_0$ is smooth, (where the $n$ in the subscript denotes the reduction modulo the $n+1$th power of the ideals of definition). This can be found for example here: Local structure theorems for smooth maps of formal schemes" JPAA 213 (2009) p1373 (Corollary 5.2)

A bit more recently, Yekutieli (maybe it was used even before) extended the notion of adic flatness to the possibly non-noetherian case (see here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01832.pdf). Is there anything known about smoothness in the non-noetherian case?

Comment: The paper arXiv:math/0504256 is superseded. The result is now published in the paper "Local structure theorems for smooth maps of formal schemes" JPAA 213 (2009) p1373. The result corresponds to Corollary 5.2 in that paper. I doubt there are published results on smoothness on non-noetherian formal schemes inasmuch they hadn't been studied in general due to lack of exactness of completion among other things.

Comment: thank you, I changed the reference above. The lack of exactness of completion maybe could be fixed by considering derived completion but I am really no expert on this.

Comment: "The lack of exactness of completion maybe could be fixed by considering derived completion", yes, but then you need derived formal schemes...